# Bootstrap popover: reload last form values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In my website I have a small login form (the usual two username and password textfields) in a Bootstrap popover.

The form is located in the HTML page, but hidden:

```
<div id="navbar-login-content" class="hidden">
                            <h4>Login</h4>

                            <form method="post" action="-----}" role="form">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="id_username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="30" name="username"
                                           id="id_username" placeholder="Username">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="id_password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" maxlength="50" name="password"
                                           id="id_password" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
</div>
```

and I load it in the popover via Javascript like this:

```
$(mypopoveritem).popover({
            content: $('#navbar-login-content').html()
        }).mouseenter(function () {
            var _this = this;
            $(this).popover("show");
```

The visualization is correct and the form works. The only problem is that when I close the popover I lose the content of the textfields and when I reopen the popover they are again blank.

I would like to keep the content of my form when I reopen the popover and I guess that, in order to do so, I should update the code of "navbar-login-content" and the reload it in the popover using the method .attr("data-content", 'value'), but I don't know hot to proceed: if I am on the right way, can you help me? otherwise can you suggest me a better way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Now I am trying to access the input fields in the popover and copy the values into the form in the base html, so it would be easier to reload it. I am accessing using var inputs = document.getElementById("navbar-login-content").getElementsByTagName('input'); . The problem is that also in this case I am not able to read the values that the user wrote in the popover form, but only the one in the corresponding base html form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work is because the popup uses an initial copy of the HTML template. When the popup is hidden, it is destroyed, along with the values. When it is open again, it will change everything back to the initial HTML template.

A possible solution for you would be to start with changing the content option for the popup to a function instead of a string:

```
$('.btn').popover({
    content: function(){
        return $('#navbar-login-content').html();
    }
})
```

This means that every time the pop up is displayed, it will get the HTML template at that point in time. The next step is to alter this HTML template when we hide the popup, to include the values that we set. Now, I personally wouldn't feel that comfortable with my password being remembered, especially being readable in HTML, so here is how to do it with just the username:

```
$('.btn').on('hide.bs.popover', function () {
    var username = $('.popover-content #id_username').val();
    $('#navbar-login-content #id_username').attr('value', username);
})
```

That should do the trick. Feel free to do the same with the password if that's what you want.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YfTYv/5/).

I've also included a different method in there for the password, where it saves the value, which is then re-entered when the pop-up is shown. There is an annoying pause before the input populates though! Here's everything together:

```
var password = '';

$('.btn').popover({
    content: function(){
        return $('#navbar-login-content').html();
    }
})

$('.btn').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    $('.popover-content #id_password').val(password);
})

$('.btn').on('hide.bs.popover', function () {
    var username = $('.popover-content #id_username').val();
    $('#navbar-login-content #id_username').attr('value', username);

    // if there is a value for the password, let's remove the placeholder to make the pause less noticeable
    password = $('.popover-content #id_password').val();
    placeholderText = password == '' ? 'Password' : '';
    $('#navbar-login-content #id_password').attr('placeholder', placeholderText);
})
```

Comment: thank you very much. Do you really think it would feel the user to be unconfortable if the password is stored in the same manner? At the end the HTML is changed locally, so there won't be the risk the password is stolen by someone else

Comment: @klebe85 Glad it helps. It's up to you regarding the password. There isn't much different if you store it in the HTML or in a javascript variable as both are accessible. I would say it depends on the context - how long the password will be stored locally for, and whether the user is aware that the password is stored.